# Overriding title for an Android share Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

It seems that Android automatically sets the title of sharing intents to the name of the app. I would like to override it to make it a little more descriptive (e.g. instead of "My App", the title could be "Preview with My App".

How can I change the title in the sharing dialogue pop up box in Android?

I have added the following code to my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Share code of your share intent as well

Answer (score 2):

`<intent-filter>` supports the attributes `android:icon` and `android:label`. You can use them to change the icon and label that are displayed in the system's Share UI.
Please note that (at least on Android 10) the app name is still displayed. So instead of "Preview with My App" you maybe want to just use "Preview" as label.

Example:

```xml
<intent-filter 
        android:icon="@drawable/share_icon"
        android:label="@string/share_label">

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

</intent-filter>
```

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element

Answer (score 1):

The key is to start your intent as an activity by passing it as an argument to `Intent.createChooser(intent: Intent)`

Here's an example in Kotlin. We all love Kotlin dont we? :)

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some Text")
            type = "text/plain"
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(this, "My Title"))
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The title has to come along with the Share Intent. So, if your application is one of the apps that can show a preview, then there is nothing you can do to show the title for choosing your app(it has to come from the calling app).

On the other hand, if you are using the Share Intent in your application itself, you can try this:

```
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "What ever text you cant to share");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Preview with:")); <---- here
```

Check the description for [createChooser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: this wont work for this intent type (ACTION_SEND) as per documention:

the Intent that the user will be selecting an activity to perform.
title – Optional title that will be displayed in the chooser, only when the target action is not ACTION_SEND or ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.